# Why does `bash -c '...'` terminate early on some (but not all) errors?

Tags: bash, kill

What is going on here?

The following works as expected:

```
$ bash -c 'false; echo $?'
1
```

But trying to kill a nonexistent process with `pkill` makes bash terminate before the script is done.

```
$ bash -c 'pkill -f xyz_non_existent_process_xyz; echo $?'
[1]    21078 terminated  bash -c 'pkill -f xyz_non_existent_process_xyz; echo $?'
```

If I run this command in the terminal, I see that `pkill` returns an error code of `1`, just like the `false` command did:

```
$ pkill -f xyz_non_existing_process_xyz; echo $?
1
```

So the two commands are returning the same status code... so what's the difference!?

I tried wrapping the command in a number of ways. For example:

```
$ bash -c '(pkill -f xyz_non_existent_process_xyz || true); echo $?'
[1]    21309 terminated  bash -c '(pkill -f xyz_non_existent_process_xyz || true); echo $?'
```

So it seems like whatever is causing bash to terminate early, it's not the exit status of any of the commands??

What's going on here?

Comment: That's bash itself being sent a `SIGTERM` by pkill, not any error internal to bash at all.

Comment: BTW, use of `pkill` is often a code smell, better replaced with use of `fuser -k` to kill whatever process holds a lockfile, or use of a proper process supervision system (`systemctl stop some-service-name`), or a kill of a specific child by PID (`foo & foo_pid=$!; ...; kill "$foo_pid"`), or some other more nuanced solution.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple: `pkill` find the bash command and stops its execution. Change the search pattern and it will function:

```
  bash -c 'pkill -f "xyz_n""on_existent_process_xyz"; echo $?'
```

It's a little bit tricky: `"xyz_n""on_existent_process_xyz"` is the same as `xyz_non_existent_process_xyz`